# Database template for population of agent specifics

Tags: anylogic

I have an agent population within an agent, so I did the following:
- I Have created an agent type "Containers"
- I have Created another agent type "Products"
- I've Opened the "Containers" agent type and draged in "Products" to create a "pop_Products" within "Containers"

My question is the following: 
Is there a template on how to create the database or how do u suggest to create the excel sheet? The information about the population of product I need are the name, amount of the batch and when it is produced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no template. AnyLogic (=Java) is flexible to read any data, you just load it (and maybe preformat it) before creating your agents.

In your case, since you can define it upfront, the best way I see:

### table "containers"

- int column "container_id"
- int column "product_id" --> link to which product
- int column "numProducts" --> amount for your container

### table "products"

- int column "product_id"
- String column "name"
- Date column "productionDate"